# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) at line 3

Tags: php, syntax, syntax-error

I'm new to php. Got this from a tutorial; for some reason it sends me an error

```
$fields_with_lengths = array('menu' => 30);
foreach ($fields_with_lengths as $fieldname => $maxlength){
    if(strlen(trim($_POST[$fieldname])) => $maxlength){
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe it should be >= ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition should be like below -- `=>` is solely for associating keys & values within arrays

```
if(strlen(trim($_POST[$fieldname])) >= $maxlength){
```

Answer (score 1):

It raises an error because equal or greater operator should be `>=` instead of `=>` (the one in the `if` statement).

Answer (score 1):

An IF statement compares two values.

`=>` is not a valid relational operator. I think what the tutorial means is `>=` which stands for 'Greater than or equal'.

Why dont you try this:

```
$fields_with_lengths = array('menu' => 30);
foreach ($fields_with_lengths as $fieldname => $maxlength){
    if(strlen(trim($_POST[$fieldname])) >= $maxlength){
         // do something..
    }
}
```